# Is There a Way to Automate XML to JSON?

Tags: json, xml, api-design

I'm working on a mean stack app that's creating and pulling json API's from a couple of sources.  We've found one obscure piece of data that is not in any of the other API's, but very important and very needed; however, the catch is we randomly found it hiding in XML as the company that puts it out did not have it in their JSON API.  What we'd like to do is just figure out a quick way to integrate that one piece of XML data into the JSON without having to go too crazy on the existing json API's.  Using an XML API from our end is not an option.  Is there anyway to make that transfer/merge into our existing json API a bit easier?  Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Could you employ an XSLT (XML Stylesheet Transform) to the XML in question, which could emit JSON?  These type conversions are fairly straightforward in XSLT.  There are a good number of examples of them out in Google and Stackoverflow.

Comment: Here is one we used with some success: https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/conf/xml-to-jsonml.xsl